# dropzone should accept case insensitive file type. Is it possible?

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone jquery plugin for files uploading.Here it should accept the extension either with "jpg, JPG, Jpg" extensions also.(formats should be case insensitive)

for example:
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = { 
  acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.psd,.svg,.properties,.xml," 
};

Here i may drop the files which has extension in capital letters (JPG,Jpg,SVG, etc.,)

In this case I am not able to drag a file,is it possible to customize?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? 
I realise im asking 5/6 years after the fact!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some validation is possible with accept callback.

From docs:

> accept    is a function that gets a file and a done function as parameter. If the done function is invoked without a parameter, the file will be processed. If you pass an error message it will be displayed and the file will not be uploaded.

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  accept: function(file, done) {
    var ext = (file.name).split('.')[1]; // get extension from file name
    if (ext == 'JPG' || ext == 'Jpg') {
      done("Dont like those extension"); // error message for user
    }
    else { done(); } // accept file
  }
};
```

Comment: Not only jpg type there are other formats also.Using this is difficult to add all type of file formats.

Comment: @mounikam so what is the point? what do you want to do? it'll be good if you can provide some snippets of your code, be more specific.

Comment: Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
 acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.psd,.svg,.properties,.xml,"
};

Here i may drop the files which has extension in capital letters (JPG,Jpg,SVG, etc.,)
In this case I am not able to drag a file